# Java Minimum and Maximum values in Array

Tags: java, arrays, max, minimum

My code does not give errors, however it is not displaying the minimum and maximum values. The code is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int array[] = new int[10];

System.out.println("Enter the numbers now.");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int next = input.nextInt();
    // sentineil that will stop loop when 999 is entered
    if (next == 999) {
        break;
    }
    array[i] = next;
    // get biggest number
    getMaxValue(array);
    // get smallest number
    getMinValue(array);
}

System.out.println("These are the numbers you have entered.");
printArray(array);


// getting the maximum value
public static int getMaxValue(int[] array) {
    int maxValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

// getting the miniumum value
public static int getMinValue(int[] array) {
    int minValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}

//this method prints the elements in an array......
//if this case is true, then that's enough to prove to you that the user input has  //been stored in an array!!!!!!!
public static void printArray(int arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Do I need a system.out.println() to display it, or should the return work?

Comment: Of course you have to print the numbers. Preferably where you invoke it. And call those two methods outside the for loop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
getMaxValue(array);
// get smallest number
getMinValue(array);
```

You are calling the methods but not using the returned values.

```
System.out.println(getMaxValue(array));
System.out.println(getMinValue(array));
```

Answer (score 18):

You can try this too, If you don't want to do this by your method.

```
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println("Min value "+arr[0]);
    System.out.println("Max value "+arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: Sorting is O(n*log(n)), finding min/max value is O(n).

Comment: Extract Answer ...its very easy.

Answer (score 6):

Imho one of the simplest Solutions is:
 -

```
//MIN NUMBER
Collections.sort(listOfNumbers);
listOfNumbers.get(0);

//MAX NUMBER
Collections.sort(listOfNumbers);
Collections.reverse(listOfNumbers);
listOfNumbers.get(0);
```

Comment: `Collections.reverse()` is unnecessary, as the last value in the sorted list is the max.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working code to find the min and max in the array.I hope you will find it helpful:

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class FindMin {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Main Method Started");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the arr");
        int size = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the maximum value of the arr");
        int max = in.nextInt();
        int [] arr  = initializeArr(max, size);
        print(arr);
        findMinMax(arr);
        System.out.println("Main Method Ended");
    }
    public static void print(int[] arr){
        for(int val:arr){
            System.out.print(val + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static int[] initializeArr(int max,int size){
        Random random = new Random();
        int [] arr = new int[size];
        for(int ii=0;ii<arr.length;ii++){
            arr[ii]=random.nextInt(max);
        }
        return arr;
    }
    public static void findMinMax(int[] arr){
        int min=arr[0];
        int max=arr[0];
        for(int ii=0;ii<arr.length;ii++){
            if(arr[ii]<min){
                min=arr[ii];
            }
            else if(arr[ii]>max){
                max=arr[ii];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum in the arr::"+min);
        System.out.println("The maximum in the arr::"+max);
    }
}
```

Comment: To lengthy approach can be done in a single line. Please find the last solution

Answer (score 5):

**Sum, Maximum and Minimum value of an Array in One Line**

```
 public static void getMinMaxByArraysMethods(int[] givenArray){

       //Sum of Array in One Line 
       long sumofArray =  Arrays.stream(givenArray).sum();

       //get Minimum Value in an array in One Line
        int minimumValue = Arrays.stream(givenArray).min().getAsInt();

        //Get Maximum Value of an Array in One Line
        int MaxmumValue =  Arrays.stream(givenArray).max().getAsInt();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just throw away Min/Max values:

```
  // get biggest number
  getMaxValue(array); // <- getMaxValue returns value, which is ignored
  // get smallest number
  getMinValue(array); // <- getMinValue returns value, which is ignored as well
```

You can do something like

```
  ... 
  array[i] = next;

  System.out.print("Max value = ");
  System.out.println(getMaxValue(array)); // <- Print out getMaxValue value

  System.out.print("Min value = ");
  System.out.println(getMinValue(array)); // <- Print out getMinValue value

  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing two mistakes here.
1. calling `getMaxValue(),getMinValue()` methods before array initialization completes.
2.Not storing return value returned by the `getMaxValue(),getMinValue()` methods.
So try this code

```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) 
  {
       int next = input.nextInt();
       // sentineil that will stop loop when 999 is entered
       if (next == 999)
       break;
       array[i] = next;
  }
  // get biggest number
  int maxValue = getMaxValue(array);
  System.out.println(maxValue );

  // get smallest number
  int minValue = getMinValue(array);
  System.out.println(minValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

your maximum, minimum method is right

but you don't print int to console!

and... maybe better location change (maximum, minimum) methods

now (maximum, minimum) methods  in the roop. it is need not.. just need one call

i suggest change this code

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
       int next = input.nextInt();
       // sentineil that will stop loop when 999 is entered
       if (next == 999)
       break;
       array[i] = next;
}
System.out.println("max Value : " + getMaxValue(array));
System.out.println("min Value : " + getMinValue(array));
System.out.println("These are the numbers you have entered.");
printArray(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use a `System.out.println`. But you are getting the minimum and maximum everytime they input a value and don't keep track of the number of elements if they break early.

Try:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
       int next = input.nextInt();
       // sentineil that will stop loop when 999 is entered
       if (next == 999)
           break;

       array[i] = next;
 }
 int length = i;
 // get biggest number
 int large = getMaxValue(array, length);
 // get smallest number
 int small = getMinValue(array, length);

 // actually print
 System.out.println( "Max: " + large + " Min: " + small );
```

Then you will have to pass length into the methods to determine min and max and to print. If you don't do this, the rest of the fields will be 0 and can mess up the proper min and max values.

Answer (score 1):

Here you haven't print the max and min values. Print the max and min values in the getMaxVal and getMin val methods or after the call. This is the output.

```
Enter the numbers now.
5
Max: 5
Min: 0
3
Max: 5
Min: 0
7
Max: 7
Min: 0
3
Max: 7
Min: 0
90
Max: 90
Min: 0
43
Max: 90
Min: 0
100
Max: 100
Min: 0
45
Max: 100
Min: 0
23
Max: 100
Min: 0
22
Max: 100
Min: 3
These are the numbers you have entered.
5 3 7 3 90 43 100 45 23 22
```

> Also when you are declaring an array, it has all 0s initially.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class Maxmin
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, min=0, max=0;
        for(i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter any number: ");
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();          
        }
        min = arr[0];
        for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i];
            }
            if(arr[i] < min)
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum is: " + min);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working as it is giving this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

//To Find Max and Min value in an array without sorting in java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class MaxMin_WoutSort {
 public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int n,max=Integer.MIN_VALUE,min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of elements: ");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      int[] arr = new int[sc.nextInt()]; //U can't say static or dynamic.
                                         //UnWrapping object sc to int value;sc.nextInt()
      System.out.println("Enter the elements: ");
      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)      //Loop for entering values in array
      {
          int next = sc.nextInt();
          arr[i] = next;
      }
      for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
     {
          if(arr[j]>max)               //Maximum Condition
            max = arr[j];
          else if(arr[j]<min)         //Minimum Condition
              min = arr[j];
     }
     System.out.println("Highest Value in array: " +max);
     System.out.println("Smallest Value in array: "+min);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your same code please compare code with your's original code :

```
public class Help {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int array[] = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers now.");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int next = input.nextInt();
        // sentineil that will stop loop when 999 is entered
        if (next == 999) {
            break;
        }
        array[i] = next;
    }

    System.out.println("These are the numbers you have entered.");
    printArray(array);

    // get biggest number
    System.out.println("Maximum: "+getMaxValue(array));
    // get smallest number
    System.out.println("Minimum: "+getMinValue(array));
}

// getting the maximum value
public static int getMaxValue(int[] array) {
    int maxValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

// getting the miniumum value
public static int getMinValue(int[] array) {
    int minValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}

//this method prints the elements in an array......
//if this case is true, then that's enough to prove to you that the user input has  //been stored in an array!!!!!!!
public static void printArray(int arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
}
```