# Android displaying Multiple markers on Map Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im having trouble zooming the start point (green marker) and end point (red marker), My code zoom in just on the end point. see the picture below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTPNq.png)

im getting my first and last data by using this:

```
   public void createMarker(int index, Double latitude, Double longitude, String location, String remarks) {

    double latitudeStart, longitudeStart;
    double latitudeEnd, longitudeEnd;

    index = index + 1;
    String text = String.valueOf(index);

    BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(index);

    IconGenerator tc = new IconGenerator(getContext());


    if (index == 1) {
        image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_green);
        latitudeStart =latitude;
        longitudeStart = longitude;
        mMapSnailTrail.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(location)
                .snippet(remarks)
                .icon(image));

    } else if (index == response_last.body().getAsJsonArray().size()) {
        image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_red);
        latitudeEnd =latitude;
        longitudeEnd = longitude;
        mMapSnailTrail.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(location)
                .snippet(remarks)
                .icon(image));
    } else {

    }

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeStart,longitudeStart));
    builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeEnd,longitudeEnd));
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    mMapSnailTrail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));

    mMapSnailTrail.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
        }
    });
}
```

the data latitude and longitude is coming from API which im getting them by this code:

```
String lati = jo.get("lat").toString();
                    String latiString = lati;
                    latiString = latiString.replace("\"", "");
                    String lat = String.valueOf(latiString);


                    String longi = jo.get("lng").toString();
                    String longiString = longi;
                    longiString = longiString.replace("\"", "");
                    String lng = String.valueOf(longiString);
```

and lastly this is the create marker that I've been using:

```
 LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    //starting point
    builder.include(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
        //end point
    builder.include(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    mMapSnailTrail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
```

i really need your help to accomplish this task. I'm searching on the internet but i can't find a solution. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, you use same `LatLng` coords `LatLng(latitude,longitude)` for zooming:

> ```
> //starting point
> builder.include(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
> //end point
> builder.include(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
> ```

May be

```
 //starting point
 builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeStart,longitudeStart));
 //end point
 builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeEnd,longitudeEnd));
```

where `(latitudeStart,longitudeStart)` - coords of start point (green marker) and `(latitudeEnd,longitudeEnd)` - coords of end point (red marker), solve the issue. You can get `latitudeStart`, `longitudeStart`, `latitudeEnd` and `longitudeEnd` this way (updated):

```
// wrong code:
// LatLng latitudeStart, longitudeStart;
// LatLng latitudeEnd, longitudeEnd;

// update2: global variables
double latitudeMin = 1000, longitudeMin = 1000;   // better get first value of lat/lon, not 1000
double latitudeMax = -1000, longitudeMax = -1000;  // better get first value of lat/lon, not -1000

...

// test current latitude is min or max
if (latitude < latitudeMin) {
    latitudeMin = latitude;
} else {
    if (latitude > latitudeMax) {
        latitudeMax = latitude;
    }
} 

// test current longitude is min or max
if (longitude< longitudeMin) {
    longitudeMin = longitude;
} else {
    if (longitude> longitudeMax) {
        longitudeMax = longitude;
    }
} 


if (index == 1) {

    image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_green);
    mMapSnailTrail.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title(location)
            .snippet(remarks)
            .icon(image));

} else if (index == response_last.body().getAsJsonArray().size()) {
    image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_red);
    mMapSnailTrail.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title(location)
            .snippet(remarks)
            .icon(image));
} else {

}

...
```

then, outside of `createMarker()`:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeMin,longitudeMin));
builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeMax,longitudeMax));
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
mMapSnailTrail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));
```

Comment: hi Andrii, having another trouble, the data type of latitude and longitude are Double (that comes from API).

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe I'm sorry: `double latitudeStart, longitudeStart` and `double latitudeEnd, longitudeEnd;` of course. Please, see updated answer.

Comment: uhm, hi again. i tried the code and needs to be initialized, so i tried latitudeStart = 0 ; longitudeStart = 0;
latitudeEnd = 0 ; longitudeEnd = 0;

but the map zooms out maximum

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe This means that you try apply zoom BEFORE you got `latitudeStart`, `longitudeStart`, `latitudeEnd` and `longitudeEnd`. Try to change your code so that at first get coordinates, then zoom applyed.

Comment: ill update my post and add my createMarker method: sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe Ypu should call `LatLngBounds.Builder builder..` and `mMapSnailTrail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));` when all `latitudeStart`, `longitudeStart`, `latitudeEnd` and `longitudeEnd` was initialized. But in `createMarker()` zoom appled every time (but `if (index == 1) {` condition selected `latitudeStart`, `longitudeStart` or `latitudeEnd` and `longitudeEnd` when `(index == response_last.body().getAsJsonArray().size())`). So move zooming part outside of `createMarker()` and call it once when all markers was added.

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe And dont forget make `latitudeStart`, `longitudeStart`, `latitudeEnd` and `longitudeEnd` global: move its declaration outside of `createMarker()` too.

Comment: i've tried to put the builder after Map ready, and returning value is all 0.0.

Comment: `getDataFromServer();
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeStart,longitudeStart));
        builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeEnd,longitudeEnd));
        Log.e ("Start", String.valueOf(latitudeStart) + " " + String.valueOf(longitudeStart));
        Log.e ("Start", String.valueOf(latitudeEnd) + " " + String.valueOf(longitudeEnd));
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        mMapSnailTrail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));`

Comment: my structure would be:
OnMapReady{
    getDataFromServer();
    createMarker();
}

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe Yes, something like that: `OnMapReady{ getDataFromServer(); createMarker(); zoomToAllMarkers(); }`.

Comment: uhm yes but i have logged it and the returning value is 0.0. i really need your help on this. thank you

Comment: i also try to log after the condition if (index == 1) ... 
it has value, now, i just want to get the value of it. i'm wondering if using if statement when getting the first and last value is appopriate?

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe yes, you should apply zoom after both `if (index == 1)` and `if (index == response_last.body().getAsJsonArray().size())` conditions: call `zoomToAllMarkers()` after all `createMarker()` calls.

Comment: this is the onMapReady. take note the CreateMarker is inside of getDataFromServer(); 

getDataFromServer();
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeStart,longitudeStart));
        builder.include(new LatLng(latitudeEnd,longitudeEnd));
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        mMapSnailTrail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));

Comment: btw, i also message you on facebook, because i cant send code snippets or screenshot of my code here

Comment: update: im getting the latitudeStart and longitudeStart only. the latend and longend is 0.0,0.0 . my solution is putting the zoom on getDataFromServer

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe So, find root cause for latend and longend is 0.0,0.0: without correct latend and longend values you can't set correct zoom. Is  latend and longend global?

Comment: i fix the code, my solution is put the LatLngBuilder on the before } of getDataFromServer() function closes. but polylines are excluded.

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe Hmm, seems zoom should be after `getDataFromServer()`.

Comment: hi, its working now. but other problem occured, the polylines are excluded for the zoom since the latStart, lngStart ,latEnd and lngEnd are the only one whose been validated

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe Seems you should not get first and last points, but border points: find minLat, minLon and maxLat, maxLon and create borders from that values.

Comment: may i ask how? sorry newbie on google map and polylines

Comment: @MikeNeriesDGorospe this is not about google map and polylines, this is about finding min and max. Something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18525474/6950238), but your values is not in array.

Comment: thank you so much @Andrii Omelchenko, i can't do this without you. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line of code

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: hi, its not working, it still zoom on the end point, my goal is display the start and end point with polylines on map. but thank you for your suggestion,

Comment: yes , i just cut the code because its so long and i need to minimize it for my question here in stackoverflow

Comment: if you didn't added refer this link 
[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial)

Comment: i have polylines sir,