# How to find the index of the largest and smallest value in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to make methods that takes numbers into an array, but I'm stuck on how to return the index of biggest/smallest value "as array".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    array();
    int max[];
}
public static void array() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Length of the Array");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    int array[] = new int[x];
    System.out.println("chose the numbers");

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
public static int max(int[] array) {

    int max = 0;
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            index = i;

        }
        {
            return index;
```

The first part is working for the length and and numbers in the array, but the return index of largest small value as array. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525474/java-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-array or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525474/java-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-array. This question has been asked many times before, just google "java index of max and min value in array site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: If performance is not much of an issue here, you can get max and min using two lines of code: `int max = Arrays.asList(array).stream().max(Integer::compare);
 int min = Arrays.asList(array).stream().min(Integer::compare);`

Comment: i want to return the 1.(index) of the largest and smallest as 2. (array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will prompt you for to enter your array and then System.out.println the min and max.

I just modified the code from this link:

https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-find-largest-number-array/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Largest_Smallest {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int n, max, min;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter number of elements in the array:");
            n = s.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n];
            System.out.println("Enter elements of array:");
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[i] = s.nextInt();
            }
            max = a[0];

            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(max < a[i])
                {
                    max = a[i];
                }
            }
            min = max;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(min > a[i])
                {
                    min = a[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Maximum value:"+max);
            System.out.println("Maximum value:"+min);
        }


  }
```