# How to display minimum and maximum values out of a list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, max, minimum

I need to display the minimum and maximum current Prices out of the list but I could only display the number at the end

```
public StockPrice() {
    char startChar = 'A';
    String tmpSymbol = null;
    int startPrice = 0;
    int priceRightNow = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < MAX_STOCKS; ++idx) {

        tmpSymbol = "" + (char) (startChar + idx) + (char) (startChar + idx + 1) + (char) (startChar + idx + 2);

        startPrice = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minStockPrice, maxStockPrice + 1);

        priceRightNow = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minStockPrice, maxStockPrice + 1);

        myStocks[idx] = new Stock(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow);
        System.out.println(myStocks[idx]);

        System.out.println();

    }
    int[] val = {priceRightNow};
    List<Integer> myStocks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer number : val ) {

        myStocks.add(number);
    }

    System.out.println("The current lowest stock price is  "  + tmpSymbol +Collections.min(myStocks));
    System.out.println("The current highest stock price is  "+ tmpSymbol +Collections.max(myStocks));
}
```

Comment: You're reassigning `tmpSymbol` each time through the loop. After the loop is done, it's the value from the last stock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Minimum and Maximum values in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525474/java-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-array)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ELdkvk6b

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding your variable.. collections.min, max should get your min, max values out of list.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        integerList.add(10);
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(12);

        System.out.println("MIN : "+Collections.min(integerList));
        System.out.println("MAX : "+Collections.max(integerList));

    }
}
```

this sample code will get you below output.

```
MIN : 1
MAX : 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `val` array contains the last `priceRightNow`. Everything you do in the previous loop iterations is irrelevant. Then the call to `ArrayList` creates a new empty list and you add the (only) value of `val` in that list. The max and the min of that list is thus the last `priceRightNow`